# How to develop WMS services in java?

Tags: development, wms, java

Can anyone point me to any resources regarding developing a custom WMS service in java? I am seeking for a tutorial for an experienced programmer, but including the details of setting up the server and the like as well as some code samples.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on how customized your WMS service needs to be I'd start by looking at [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org) which provides WMS out of the box.  It's implemented in Java under the GPL license so may, or may not work for you depending on your requirements.

Comment: Here are tutorials for Geoserver (http://geoserver.org/display/GEOSDOC/4+Tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

I would first go with Yeroc's answer, but you can also try [SimpleMapServer](http://glmapserver.sourceforge.net/).